# Why isn't this multiline Java pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, multiline

I thought I had understood the way those delimiters match on Java regexps, and how the multiline modifier affects it, but in the end I can't get this simple code sample to give me the expected result.

Also read several simmilar questions on SO and the solution is always using the `(?m)` modifier. So, what is wrong with this example?

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("foo\nTAG\nbar".matches("(?m)^TAG$") ? "matches" : "dont match");
     }
}
```

Prints don't match. Can be tested at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Not sure what is happening but `matches` tries to match the whole string not part of it.

Comment: Oh god. So that is exactly the problem. Please post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matches method tries to match the whole input string. So change your regex like below to get a match. In multiline mode `(?m)`,  dot won't match a newline character. To match any character including newline , you need to use `[\S\s]` which  matches a space or non-space character.

In Dotall mode `(?s)`, you could simply use `.*` to match any character (*including newline character*) zero or more times.

Modifiers can even be combined as `(?ms)` to get advantage of the best of both modes.

```
System.out.println("foo\nTAG\nbar".matches("(?m)[\\s\\S]*^TAG$[\\s\\S]*") ? "matches" : "dont match");
System.out.println("foo\nTAG\nbar".matches("(?s).*?(^|\n)TAG(\n|$).*") ? "matches" : "dont match");
System.out.println("foo\nTAG\nbar".matches("(?ms).*?^TAG$.*") ? "matches" : "dont match");
```

**Output:**

```
matches
matches
matches
```